# Como puede mostrar el url en consola con c# , con la hora y la fecha de la descarga y que se guarde

Tags: c#

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient ())  { 
   Client.DownloadFile("http://");  }
```

---

Comment: que seria mostrar la url en consola? sabes que la consola no dibuja html? Luego deberias explicar tu problema en el contenido de la pregunta y no solo con un titulo y agregar algo mas de codigo que hayas realizado

Answer (score 0):

El truco sería lanzar en la linea siguiente a la descarga la impresión en consola:

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient ())  
{ 
        string url = "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417580/como-puede-mostrar-el-url-en-consola-con-c-con-la-hora-y-la-fecha-de-la-desca";
        Client.DownloadFile(url, "c:holamundo.html");
        System.Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + url);  
}
```

`Client.Download` te faltaba el parámetro de donde guardarlo.